# Knockout JS remove option if value is greater than (on foreach)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a json array that has a device name and quantity. If the quantity is two and the user adds two items to the foreach for that name (they select from the drop down field) I'd like to hide that device name option from the drop down menu.

****Edit****
Rune seems that he has the correct answer, however I cannot figure out how to integrate it into my code. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/QTUqD/1/

```
<form id="extMngForm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Voicemail Pin</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>MAC Address</th>
                <th>Ship To</th>
                <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- ko if: pagedList().length < extQty() -->
    <p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Extension</a></p>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div class="pagination pull-left">
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">Previous</a></li></ul>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: allPages">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</a></li></ul>
    </div>

    <br clear="all" />
    <script id="extItems" type="text/html">
       <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: extension"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: vmpin"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: device"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: macAddress"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: shipTo"></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script id="editExts" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="extension" data-bind="value: extension" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="name" data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="vmpin" data-bind="value: vmpin" /></td>
            <td>

            <select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.devices, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: device"></select>

            </td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" name="macAddress" data-bind="value: macAddress" /></td>
            <td><select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.addressList, optionsText: 'locationName', optionsValue: 'shipping_address_street', value: shipTo"></select></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</form>
<form id="extMngForm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Voicemail Pin</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>MAC Address</th>
                <th>Ship To</th>
                <th style="width: 100px; text-align:right;" />
            </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody data-bind=" template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: pagedList }"></tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- ko if: pagedList().length < extQty() -->
    <p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.add" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Extension</a></p>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <div class="pagination pull-left">
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === 0 }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: previousPage">Previous</a></li></ul>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: allPages">
            <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.pageNumber === ($root.pageIndex() + 1) }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data.pageNumber, click: function() { $root.moveToPage($data.pageNumber-1); }"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul><li data-bind="css: { disabled: pageIndex() === maxPageIndex() }"><a href="#" data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</a></li></ul>
    </div>

    <br clear="all" />
    <script id="extItems" type="text/html">
       <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: extension"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
            <td style="width:20px;" data-bind="text: vmpin"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: device"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: macAddress"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: shipTo"></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.edit" href="#" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>

    <script id="editExts" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="extension" data-bind="value: extension" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="name" data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="email" data-bind="value: email" /></td>
            <td style="width:20px;"><input data-errorposition="b" class="required" name="vmpin" data-bind="value: vmpin" /></td>
            <td>

            <select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.devices, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: device"></select>

            </td>
            <td><input data-errorposition="b" name="macAddress" data-bind="value: macAddress" /></td>
            <td><select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.addressList, optionsText: 'locationName', optionsValue: 'shipping_address_street', value: shipTo"></select></td>
            <td class="buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
                <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.remove" href="#" title="remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</form>
```

---

```
window.ExtListViewModel = new function () {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;

    self.list = ko.observableArray();

    self.pageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.extQty = ko.observable();
    self.devices = ko.observableArray(['devices']);


    self.addressList = ko.observableArray(['addressList']);
    self.edit = function (item) {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            self.selectedItem(item);
        }
    };

    self.cancel = function () {
        self.selectedItem(null);
    };

    self.add = function () {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            var newItem = new Extension();
            self.list.push(newItem);
            self.selectedItem(newItem);
            self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
        }
    };
    self.remove = function (item) {

            if (confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {

                    self.list.remove(item);
                    if (self.pageIndex() > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                        self.moveToPage(self.maxPageIndex());
                    }

            }
            $('.error').hide();
    };
    self.save = function () {
        if($('#extMngForm').valid()) {
            self.selectedItem(null);
        };
    };

    self.templateToUse = function (item) {
        return self.selectedItem() === item ? 'editExts' : 'extItems';
    };

    self.pagedList = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        return self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    });
    self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.list().length / self.pageSize()) - 1;
    });
    self.previousPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.nextPage = function () {
        if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
            self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
            pages.push({ pageNumber: (i + 1) });
        }
        return pages;
    });
    self.moveToPage = function (index) {
        self.pageIndex(index);
    };


};


ko.applyBindings(ExtListViewModel, document.getElementById('extMng'));

function Extension(extension, name, email, vmpin, device, macAddress, shipTo){
    this.extension = ko.observable(extension);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.email = ko.observable(email);
    this.vmpin = ko.observable(vmpin);
    this.device = ko.observable(device);
    this.macAddress = ko.observable(macAddress);
    this.shipTo = ko.observable(shipTo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on adding a new computed for available devices on the main viewmodel object, plus a helper function. It's not ideal for all cases and there's probably ways to simplify this, but I've run out of juice for now :P

```
self.availableDevices = ko.computed(function() {        
    var usedQuantities = {}; // for each device id, store the used quantity
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.list(), function(item) {
        var device = item.device();
        if (device) {
            usedQuantities[device.id] = 1 + (usedQuantities[device.id] || 0);
        }
    });

    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.devices(), function(device) {
        var usedQuantity = usedQuantities[device.id] || 0;
        return device.quantity > usedQuantity;
    });
});


// need this to add back item's selected device to its device-options,
// and to maintain original order of devices
self.devicesForItem = function(item) {        
    var availableDevices = self.availableDevices();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.devices(), function(device) {
        return device === item.device() || availableDevices.indexOf(device) !== -1;
    });
}
```

and the corresponding binding (note: no use of optionsValue):

```
<select style="width:100px;" data-bind="options: $root.devicesForItem($data), optionsText: 'name', value: device"></select>
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/QTUqD/6/

Some other small changes I made to your fiddle so it'll work: changed extQty to 20, added example devices, fixed element ID for ko.applyBindings, commented form validation stuff.. maybe a couple more ;p (also included different bootstrap css)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this answer. I'm integrating it with my ajax data and I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [{id:"gxp2100",name:"Grandstream GXP-2100",qty:"3",byod:"0"},{id:"pcom331",name:"Polycom 331",qty:"2",byod:"0"}] has no method 'filter' 

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 with a few other script do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: filter should be available in modern browsers, but you can use KO's array functions instead, i'll update the code to use them.

Comment: either that, or you're putting a string into your viewmodel instead of a real array

Comment: This is how I'm sending it:
`success: function (result) {        var deviceListObject = result.devices;        ExtListViewModel.devices(deviceListObject);`

And when I alert that with JSON.stringify I get this:
`[{"id":"gxp2100","name":"Grandstream GXP-2100","qty":"3","byod":"0"},{"id":"pcom331","name":"Polycom 331","qty":"2","byod":"0"}]`

Comment: it doesn't work with the KO functions either? don't alert, use console.log, without JSON.stringify.. anyway I can't help further without seeing what you're doing in more detail.. if you're still having trouble maybe you should open a new SO post and give more details or a demo (you can mock ajax requests on jsfiddle), because this is a separate issue

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how your markup or view model looks like, I'm assuming you're mapping your devices. I would map the following "*Device*" object and work with it. To be more specific, I'd have to see your code in a JSBin or something.

```
var Device = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, self);
   // self.name added via mapping
   // self.quantity added via mapping 
   self.numberOfDevicesShown = ko.observable();
   self.showDevice = ko.computed(function(){ // use this property in the markup
       return self.numberOfDevicesShown() >= self.quantitity();
   })
};

var viewModelMapping = {
    'devices': {
        create: function(options) {
        return new Device(options.data);
    }
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,viewModelMapping,self);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    vm = new ViewModel(initialViewModelData);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

In your markup you can do something like this:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: devices">
    <!-- ko if: showDevice -->
        <option></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

You can read more about mapping in the **Customizing object construction using “create”** and **Customizing object updating using “update”** sections [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Comment: Wow thank you for all this. It seems like it would work but I'm having problems integrating it, I should of posted my code initially, sorry about that. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QTUqD/
This is the code that I need to do the conditional on:
<select style="width:80px;" data-bind="options: $root.devices, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: device"></select>

The data is getting sent over from another view model with an Ajax request like this: ExtListViewModel.devices(result.devices);

Comment: Did you have any questions on the comment I had above? I am still having issues sorting out the code with what you have given me above.

Comment: the jsfiddle has a bunch of things that don't work - if you can bring it into a state where it works minus the functionality that you're looking for it's easier to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: It is something to do with the script tags in the HTML I'm pretty sure.
This is the script it is based off of: http://blog.ryanvanderpol.com/index.php/2012/07/using-knockoutjs-to-create-an-edit-in-place-data-grid/

Comment: I doubt you want to be doing `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, self);` only to be followed with `self.name = ko.observable();` etc. which will overwrite what you just mapped. And on another note, quantitity++

Comment: @antishok Do you have any suggestions on how I can implement to the code I posted in the main question?